# What’s this circle metal on the wall?

Tags: closet

I was going to install wire shelves in one of the closets, but this shiny circle thing will cause the shelve to not flush.

[image]

Anybody knows what it is?

Comment: A broken hook or bracket?

Comment: A drain cleanout cover?   What is on the other side of the wall?  Can you open the screw in the middle?

Comment: looks like a light fixture to me,  I see a wire pigtail inside the dome.

Comment: what is preventing you from removing the cover?

Comment: Based on your reflection in the dome it appears to be low on the wall which indicates it's probably a fancy drain cleanout cover. @jay613 should write it up as an answer.

Comment: If it's low on the wall or at knob height, it could be a protector against the door hitting the wall.  Otherwise, take it off and see what goblins come out

Comment: I won't make this an answer without some simple answers to simple questions.  1) There is some writing around the screw.  What does it say?  2) Remove the screw and the cover, and post a photo of what's inside 3) Tell us what's on the other side of the wall 4) If there is an unfinished basement underneath, tell us or post photos of what is directly underneath.   I'm expecting all that to corroborate or disprove it's a cleanout.

Comment: Wouldn't it be fun if the writing around the screw [actually said](https://www.amazon.com/Danco-80028-2-Inch-Cleanout-Chrome/dp/B001GTTNCU) "cleanout cover" ? :)

Comment: @jay613 I think you’re right. I found similar on Amazon, but not with that lip and embossing around the screw. Note that this is chrome over the whole surface, but reflections of the wall and what looks like wire shelving are deceiving. There is no translucent section. Zoom in and it’s obvious.

Comment: @jay613 you’re right. It turned out to be a cleanout cover.